# How does assigning in the post section of a Go for loop allow this loop to exit?

Tags: go

I'm working through "The Go Programming Language" book and have come across what is an unusual for loop syntax in chapter 5. I've cut down the example below, but the whole program is [on the book's GitHub page](https://github.com/adonovan/gopl.io/blob/master/ch5/findlinks1/main.go).

```
type Node struct {
    int                     NodeType
    FirstChild, NextSibling *Node
}

func visit(n *Node) {
  for c:= n.FirstChild; c != nil; c = c.NextSibling {
    visit(c)
  }
}
```

The C parser in my head tells me that `c.NextSibling` will always either point to a `Node` or be `nil`. In that case the loop should either then always break or continue forever.

When `c.NextSibling` is not `nil`, it seems that the loop is exiting as the loop value is the same as the previous iteration, but I couldn't find anything in the [Go Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements) to back that up.

I've compiled that program and confirm that it works as per the book.

Am I missing something fundamental or is something else going on here?

---

Full example, with instrumented code (thanks to Sergio):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Node struct {
    NodeId                  int
    FirstChild, NextSibling *Node
}

func visit(n *Node) {
    fmt.Printf("Entering node %d\n", n.NodeId)
    for c := n.FirstChild; c != nil; c = nextSib(c) {
        fmt.Printf("Will now visit node %d\n", c.NodeId)
        visit(c)
    }
}

func nextSib(n *Node) *Node {
    next := n.NextSibling
    fmt.Printf("In nextSib for %d %t\n", n.NodeId, next != nil)
    return next
}

func main() {
    c4 := &Node{NodeId: 5}
    c3 := &Node{NodeId: 4}
    c2 := &Node{NodeId: 3, NextSibling: c3}
    c1 := &Node{NodeId: 2, FirstChild: c4, NextSibling: c2}
    root := &Node{NodeId: 1, FirstChild: c1}

    visit(root)
}
```

Output:

```
Entering node 1
Will now visit node 2
Entering node 2
Will now visit node 5
Entering node 5
In nextSib for 5 false
In nextSib for 2 true
Will now visit node 3
Entering node 3
In nextSib for 3 true
Will now visit node 4
Entering node 4
In nextSib for 4 false
```

Comment: Are you saying that the loop will exit while `c.NextSibling` is non-nil? That's impossible. Would you care to prepare a [mcve] so that we can see ourselves (with input and all. Just create and link some nodes manually)

Comment: Yeah this is the opposite of the "why is programme in an infinite loop" question :D. I'm obviously missing something, but I can't see what.

Comment: Do you perhaps see `visit` descend into node's children and interpret that as "exiting the loop"?

Comment: There is really nothing weird here. Perhaps it helps if you see the loop re-written with goto? https://play.golang.org/p/nAtSUWkvJBw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When `c.NextSibling` is not nil, it seems that the loop is exiting as the loop value is the same as the previous iteration

Not sure what you meant by that, but yes, you're misinterpreting *something*. But `for` loop is not to blame. It most certainly [does not exit](https://play.golang.org/p/4ghE8cvOp_h) while its continue condition is still true.

```
type Node struct {
    NodeId                  int
    FirstChild, NextSibling *Node
}

func visit(n *Node) {
    for c := n.FirstChild; c != nil; c = c.NextSibling {
        fmt.Printf("seeing node %d\n", c.NodeId)
        visit(c)
    }
}

func main() {
    c3 := &Node{NodeId: 4}
    c2 := &Node{NodeId: 3, NextSibling: c3}
    c1 := &Node{NodeId: 2, NextSibling: c2}
    root := &Node{NodeId: 1, FirstChild: c1}

    visit(root)
}
```

Output

```
seeing node 2
seeing node 3
seeing node 4
```

Comment: Thanks for the link to the playpen: I've instrumented this further to show there are for loops in each of the recursive calls https://play.golang.org/p/jadUjzMHBBc. Also to check that it still works when `FirstChild` and `NextSibling` are non nil. I've made the `post` a function to be able to instrument that which I think is key. And for node 2, `nextSib` is called only once.

Comment: `In nextSib for 2 true` - shouldn't that cause the loop to run again?

Comment: @PaulAnnetts "shouldn't that cause the loop to run again?" - and it does. The loop advances to node 3, the next sibling

Comment: Ok - got it. It's the sibling *of the child* node. So you're not looping over the node, you're looping over the children. I see my mistake.

Comment: Instrumented playpen at https://play.golang.org/p/asaCjzQCEgQ clearly shows the parent and child node...

Comment: @PaulAnnetts: I got confused by the wording for a second, but yes, you're right, you're looping over node's children

Comment: Yeah - recursive code is fun: better hope that the graph of Nodes doesn't have a cycle in it anywhere :).